# Определить ИД пользователя ВК

Tags: php, vkontakte-api

Пользователь со страницы ВК заходит на страницу подписки (е-мейл) на моем сайте, заполняет поля, а при нажатии кнопки "отправить" мой сайт определяет его ИД в ВК и подставляет его в этот код:

```
$request = 'http://api.vkontakte.ru/method/users.get?uids=ID&fields=photo_200,status';
$response = file_get_contents($request);
$info = array_shift(json_decode($response)->response);

var_dump($info->photo_200); // URL фотографии
var_dump($info->status);    // Статус
```

Как это реализовать?

Comment: Можно, если он перед этим сделает авторизацию через АПИ вконтакте и разрешит действия на манипулирования его данными